# Can angular2 routes be indexed by Google bots unlike angular 1?

Tags: google-analytics, seo, angular, angular2-routing

I'm curious can angular 2 spa be indexed?

Google in the past would only index the first page eg homepage

Does angular 2 solve this issue?

I here that Google have been indexing JavaScript and css files for a while now.

Do I need to do anything to my angular 2 app in order for all routes to be indexed in my app?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Google now provide server side rendering for Angular 2 ( with NodeJS, i am not sure for other platforms ). That will be beneficial for SEO.

Also, setting PathLocationStrategy ( myurl.com/article/braking-news ) instead of HashLocationStrategy ( myurl.com/#/article/braking-news ) make URLs to look prettier.

Comment: So just to clarify angular 2 is no different to angular 1 when it comes to pages being indexed for a single paged app?

Comment: Out of the box, no. But you have workarounds to do that.